# Where does Ohm's Law, Kirchhoff circuit laws, etc, come from?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, ohms-law, physics, formula-derivation

I know that these various laws that we use are often commonly accepted in practice but I am always curious how far down the rabbit hole you can do until you hit something that you just accept as true.

Can Ohm's Law and the Kirchhoff circuit laws be boiled down or derived from even more fundamental means or are they simply "things that fit observation and intuition so closely that there's no reason to look deeper"?

For example I always wonder if Ohm's law applies all the same even if you have super thick wires? An inch thick? A foot thick? A mile thick? What if they aren't even wires, but something like a sheet of metal instead?

I'm just trying to understand how to wrap my head around where these laws come from, why they work, in what situations might they not work, if there is some more "general" approach that happens to simplify down to the versions we use in 99.9999% of use cases, that sort of thing.

What's the bigger picture?

Comment: Ohm's law applies for all resistive materials in the absence of strong magnetic fields. It does not apply in the case of a p-n junction or a Schottky junction, or under breakdown conditions like inside a gas discharge tube. Kirchhoff's current law applies at all times (remember to count displacement current), and Kirchhoff's voltage law applies whenever there's no changing magnetic field. Open to being corrected on any of these, since there seem to always be edge cases.

Comment: Why not start by checking out the work of Sir George Simon Ohm etc ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Ohm (Note that it's "Georg" not "George")

Comment: "What's the bigger picture?" - Maxwell's equations.

Comment: they arent arbitrary or made up, just think about how electricity works/moves, thick/thin, solid/stranded, etc, you can do the theoretical math the you can apply imperfections in the materials.   I am sure there are a number of universities that have exposed their electrical engineering and physics and chemistry (and materials, etc) lectures so you can fully understand it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad, seeking external resources for basic electronics education.

Comment: @VicenteCunha thanks, I think that's the next step I needed

Comment: I believe Ohm's Law was first determined through experimentation at the macro-level first. Then people built downward (and upward) with it. I don't know about Kirchoff. By the way, you are referring to the lumped model, in case you did not know. Below is when things are treated as unlumped, continuous distributions (i.e. calculus) and is used to take into account the actual geometry of things rather than just treating it as a single number. Then below that is stuff like quantum physics.

Answer (score 1):

Ohms law can be extended to volume resistivites, you need to know the volume or surface resistivity

[image]
Source: https://www.napson.co.jp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/%e5%9b%b3_en-01.png

Comment: So do these other factors disappear or become negligible somehow when you start looking at the typical very-small and very-short copper traces in a common circuitboard?

Answer (score 0):

Ohms Law was result of measurements, by George Ohm, in the British Cavendish Lab, where a large "Volta pile" provided rather steady voltages even at high currents. If I recall rightly, this was in very early 1800s. [This is from a specific paper in IEEE Proceedings, about 2015. ]

Ohm was a skilled mathematician and physicist, thus likely afraid of nothing.

Kirchoff did his work (or at least published it) in 1840s.

==============================================

Now ---- to your question ---- where do these come from?

From philosophy.

Phenomena are observed.

Causality proposed.

Variables considered.

Equations merge.

And at any point, measurements are done.

HUMMANS perform full_factorial exploration of phenomena, within our minds. All possible corners of the search_space are examined, pruned, linearized if useful, gradients examined and used for prediction, cusps and cliffs and saddles noted as the maths are proposed.

Rene Decartes is quoted, in the 1960s Encyclopedia of Philosophy, as defining the FOUR STEPS of understanding.

I will add those later, to this answer.

To summaryize Decartes 4 steps ---- pore over all the possibly relevant obsrvations and data and measurements and equipment and conclussions and conflicts.

And every time a new fact or datapoint or equation or variable emerges, then set the brain/mind to full and complete and intense re-thinking of ALL that is possibly relevant.

Thus George Ohm was skilled in math and physics, afraid of nothing, willing to let his mind perform as Descartes specified, those 200 years earlier.

Comment: Was about to accept answer until I noticed the completely unnecessary and clearly-mocking edits. Removing upvote